# Interpolation between two matrices

Tags: python, matrix, interpolation

I have two matrices that represent the values of a quantity on a grid at different times.
I would like to create a third matrix at an intermediate time, whose pixel are interpolated between the two matrices.

I tried with a simple linear interpolation for each pixel, but if I visualize the end product with `imshow` I don't really have a smooth transition between the frames.

I can't provide a direct example because I'm dealing with a huge dataset but I was wondering whether anyone has ever had a similar problem.

I'm aware of the `scipy.interpolate` functions, but they seem to come in handy only to interpolate a set of discrete points.

Comment: What about [`scipy.interpolate.griddata`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata)? It takes "an array of size (N, ndim), or a tuple of ndim arrays".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the original data is already gridded, you could use `ndimage.map_coordinates` to interpolate:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# given 2 arrays arr1, arr2
arr1 = np.linspace(0, 1, 100).reshape(10,10)
arr2 = np.linspace(1, 0, 100).reshape(10,10)

# rejoin arr1, arr2 into a single array of shape (2, 10, 10)
arr = np.r_['0,3', arr1, arr2]

# define the grid coordinates where you want to interpolate
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(10), np.arange(10))
# 0.5 corresponds to half way between arr1 and arr2
coordinates = np.ones((10,10))*0.5, X, Y

# given arr interpolate at coordinates
newarr = ndimage.map_coordinates(arr, coordinates, order=2).T
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=3)
cmap = plt.get_cmap('Greys')

vmin = np.min([arr1.min(), newarr.min(), arr2.min()])
vmax = np.max([arr1.max(), newarr.max(), arr2.max()])
ax[0].imshow(arr1, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
ax[1].imshow(newarr, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
ax[2].imshow(arr2, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
ax[0].set_xlabel('arr1')
ax[1].set_xlabel('interpolated')
ax[2].set_xlabel('arr2')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the matrices to be numpy arrays and since you've only got two points, you could simply implement the (linear) interpolation yourself:

```
def interp(m1, t1, m2, t2, t_interp):
    return m1 + (m2-m1) / (t2-t1) * (t_interp-t1)
```

Where `m1`/`m2` can be arbitrarily shaped numpy arrays and `t1`/`t2` their corresponding time-values. t_interp would be time-value at which to interpolate.
So this gives `m1` for `t_interp = t1` and `m2` for `t_interp = t2`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but as I said it the question this is what I have been trying before. Is there a more sophisticated method?